# How to find inverse of this function (Mutual Information)?

Tags: calculus, information-theory

I am looking at a real-value random variable $A$ that is defined as

\begin{equation}
 A = \mu_A.x+n_A
\end{equation}

where $n_A\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_A^2)$. Also $\mu_A = \frac{\sigma_A^2}{2}$ and $x\in[+1,-1]$ with equal probability i-e $P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=1/2$.

I am defining $I_A$ *(mutual information)* as

\begin{equation}
 I_A = 1-{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-((\xi-(\sigma_A^2/2).x)^2)/2\sigma_A^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_A}\log [1+e^\xi]d\xi} \tag{*}
\end{equation}

where $0\leq I_A \leq 1$. For abbreviation I define

\begin{equation}
 J(\sigma) := I_A(\sigma_A=\sigma)  \tag{**}
\end{equation}

$J(\cdot)$ is monotonically increasing in $\sigma =2/\sigma_n$ and is reversible.

\begin{equation}
 \sigma_A = J^{-1}(I_A)  \tag{***}
\end{equation}

My question is what is the *closed form expression* of $\sigma_A$. I know that we can use *Q-function* for computing the tail probability of a Gaussian function but here I have $log [1+e^\xi]$ factor.

This might sound simple but I don't have good calculus skills and so am shaky in making an attempt here. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

$\underline{BACKGROUND}$

The conditional probability distribution function is given as

\begin{equation}
 p_A(\xi\mid X=x) = \frac{e^{-((\xi-(\sigma_A^2/2).x)^2)/2\sigma_A^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_A}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

The mutual information $I_A=I(X;A)$ between $X$ and $A$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
 I_A = \sum_{x\in X}\hspace{1mm}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p(x,\xi)\log \left(\frac{p(x,\xi)}{p(x)p(\xi)}\right)d\xi} \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Applying law of total probability and using (1), we get

\begin{equation}
 I_A = \frac{1}{2}.\sum_{x=-1,+1}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p_A(\xi\mid X=x)\log \left(\frac{2.p_A(\xi\mid X=x)}{p_A(\xi\mid X=-1)+p(\xi\mid X=1)}\right)d\xi} \tag{3}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
 0\leq I_A \leq 1 \tag{4}
\end{equation}

With (2) and (3) I get

\begin{equation}
 I_A = 1-{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-((\xi-(\sigma_A^2/2).x)^2)/2\sigma_A^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_A}\log [1+e^\xi]d\xi} \tag{5}
\end{equation}

Comment: It looks strange that $\mu_A = \frac{\sigma_A^2}{2}$ (units seem inconsistent). Are you sure it's not $\sigma_A$ in the numerator?

Comment: Yes. I got this information from a research paper.